# Does jQuery UI dialog box text have a newline option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a website using data from Pokemon and trying to execute a dialog box. I've tried using JS newline character in the text:

```
function alertBox(monster) {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", monster);
    $("#dialog").text("Height: "  + pokemon.height[monster] + "\n" +
                      "Weight: " + pokemon.weight[monster]);
}
```

...And I've also tried using the html line break tag:

```
function alertBox(monster) {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", monster);
    $("#dialog").text("Height: "  + pokemon.height[monster] + "<\br>" +
                      "Weight: " + pokemon.weight[monster]);
}
```

But neither seems to be returning the newline effect I'm looking for! The JS newline just acts as a space and the html line break tag just concatenates to the string. Is there a way to force a newline in the dialog text?

Comment: why are ther "<br>"s all over the place?

Comment: Use `.html()` with `<br />` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: has nothing to do with using a  dialog... it's the way html works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The jQuery [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) function automatically escapes HTML entities, so your `<br />` tag is no longer being interpreted as HTML, but instead gets converted to escaped text.

To prevent this HTML escaping, you need to use [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to set the contents:

```
function alertBox(monster) {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", monster);
    $("#dialog").html("Height: "  + pokemon.height[monster] + "<br />" +
                      "Weight: " + pokemon.weight[monster]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding:

```
$("#dialog").css("white-space","pre-wrap");
```

This will make the `\n` significant, and it will render as such.

Alternatively, consider using some actual HTML. For instance, your dialog could be:

```
$("#dialog").html("<ul>" +
    "<li><b>Height:</b> "+pokemon.height[monster]+"</li>" +
    "<li><b>Weight:</b> "+pokemon.weight[monster]+"</li>" +
"</ul>");
```

For more complex layouts, I'd suggest using a templating system instead of hardcoding HTML into your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help to see how text() val() and html() works

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dialog").html("Height: " + 11 + "<br>" +
        "Weight: " + 22);

    $("#dialog2").val("Height: " + 11 + "\n" +
        "Weight: " + 22);

    $("#dialog3").text("Height: " + 11 + "\n" +
        "Weight: " + 22);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="dialog"></div>
<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="text" id="dialog2"></textarea>
<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="text" id="dialog3"></textarea>
```